# Having problems sending private message in a socket.io room using redis

Tags: node.js, laravel, redis, socket.io

I'm trying to build a secure private facebook like messaging system  using laravel, redis pub/sub and socket io. All the console.log functions log the messages to say everything went through on the node server and everything works fine untill I try and emit the message to the client. When I try to emit the message to the client nothing at all happens.

*Although I don't think my controller method on laravel is of significance here it is anyway. You can skip the Laravel controller if it's not necessary*

**Laravel Message Controller:**

```
public function store($id, Request $request)
{
    //Stores message in $message

    //Connects redis
    $redis = Redis::connection();

    $data = ['message' => $request->input('message'), 'user' => Auth::user()->name,
     'room' => $message->conversation_id];
    $redis->publish('message', json_encode($data));

    return Redis::get('message');
    response()->json([]);
}
```

**Redis stuff being published in JSON output:**

```
{message: 'some message', user: 'john doe', room: 1}
```

**Node Server**

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var redis = require('redis');

server.listen(3000);
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  console.log("client connected");
  var redisClient = redis.createClient();
  redisClient.subscribe('message');

  redisClient.on("message", function(channel, data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);

    socket.join(data.room, function() {
      console.log('Joined room '+data.room);
    }); 
    console.log("new message add in queue "+ data.room + " channel");
    socket.to(data.room).emit(channel, data);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    redisClient.quit();
  });

});
```

**Client Side JS**

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
socket.on('message', function (data) {
    //Just console the message and user right now.
    console.log(data.message+" " + data.user);
});
```

I don't know if my problem is that I'm not specifying the room on the client. If so is there any way of emitting the data to the client without specifying the room in the client side code? Why can't I emit the message to the client?

Comment: try socket.broadcast.to(room).emit('my message', msg);  to emit to all clients in the room EXCEPT the socket that initiated the call

Comment: I'm getting a different problem now, but it's the same socket.to() and socket.broadcast().

The messages are sending, but now all of the clients can view the message. Even the ones out side the room.

Comment: check the number of sockets in a room
var roster = io.sockets.clients('chatroom1');

console.log(roster.length)

Comment: I keep getting this error:

    **if (fn) process.nextTick(fn.bind(null, null, sids));
                              ^
    TypeError: fn.bind is not a function**

Comment: I'm also getting duplicate posts in chat when ever I send a message.

Comment: With my own experience it was a pleasure to switch over and use laravel-echo-server basically replaces the need for managing the node server part - once all is in place it just works.

Comment: From what I've seen I would still need to configure the node server to use roughly the same code I have. I also don't want to use pusher as its limited in channels.      https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/step-by-step-guide-to-installing-socketio-and-broadcasting-events-with-laravel-51